# MMenu button jumping up when mmenu is opened

Tags: jquery, position, fixed, mmenu

Been playing around with the mmenu plugin for a while now and can't seem to get over this particular bug.So I have the mmenu plugin on my sidebar. On load the menu is closed and can be opened/closed with a button placed vertically on the middle of the container. When you open the menu all is well. When you scroll to the bottom of the page and open the menu from there, the button jumps up.

The button is as follows:

```
<nav id="desktop-button" class="pull-out hidden-xs hidden-sm fixed navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="sidebar--pullout">
        <div class="inner">
             <a class="sidebar--pullout-anchor">Menu</a>
         </div>
      </div>
</nav>
```

The styling:

```
.pull-out {
    background-color: #333;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: auto;
    left: -2px;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 30px;
}
.sidebar--pullout {
    background-color: #333;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 0;
    box-shadow: 3px 0 2px #000000;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
    box-shadow: 3px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -o-box-shadow: 3px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.inner {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -10px;
}
.sidebar--pullout-anchor {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    position: relative;
    top: 50vh;
    bottom: 50vh;
}
```

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: add sample in jsfiddle

Comment: I have a similar problem. I have a list with links to open the menu. When I'm opening the menu after I scroll down, it jump up to the top of the page and then show the menu. If I'm canceling the menu, the page state is on the top, and not the original place where I clicked the menu. Anyone knows how to stay in the same position when opening the menu?